# linux sort only by the first letter of each line

Tags: linux, sorting

what's the fastest way to sort file by the first letter of each line?  should one use linux sort command or are there other more efficient alternatives?
if I am using sort, how do I sort only by the first letter and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will sort by the first character

```
sort -k1.1,1.1 filename
```

add `-s` if you want to preserve the input order of lines with the same first character

Comment: how do I ignore the first line of the file?  what does the 1.1 mean?

Comment: The `-k` option defines the key in terms of "fields" and "characters within fields", where fields are blank-delimited. There are options for changing the field delimiter.  The spec `1.1,1.1` says the sort key starts at field 1 position 1 and ends at the same place.  Read the man page for `sort` for more info.  By "ignore the first line" do you mean remove it from the output, or make it come out first in the output even though that's not where it would sort?  I suggest you post that as another SO question.